# WCF Callback not calling back

Tags: c#, wcf, callback

I have read many articles here on SO, and on MSDN and Code Project. And still the answer eludes me.

I have created a WCF service that has a callback contract, and a Windows Forms app (test harness) that implements the callback interface.

Here are the interfaces:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICacheService
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool AddToCache(string type, string key, string source, object item, int duration);


    [OperationContract]
    bool Remove(string key);
}



[ServiceContract(SessionMode=SessionMode.Required, CallbackContract=typeof(ISearchCallback))]
public interface ICacheSearch
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
    void SearchCache(string source);
}



public interface ISearchCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
    void OnCallback(object data);
}
```

My service (left out the Add and Remove to conserve space - they work as expected):

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class CachingService : ICacheService, ICacheSearch, IDisposable
{
    private List<ICache> _cacheList = new List<ICache>();
    private ISearchCallback _callback = null;


    public void SearchCache(string source)
    {
        try
        {
            _callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ISearchCallback>();
            List<object> items = new List<object>();
            foreach (ICache cache in this._cacheList)
            {
                foreach (CacheItem item in cache.GetCacheItemsBySource(source))
                {
                    items.Add(item.Value);
                }
            }

            ReadOnlyCollection<object> outList = new ReadOnlyCollection<object>(items);
            _callback.OnCallback(outList);
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

My service is hosted in a Windows Service. Here is the system.serviceModel section from app.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding 
          name="WSHttpBinding_ICacheService" 
          closeTimeout="00:01:00" 
          openTimeout="00:01:00" 
          receiveTimeout="00:01:00" 
          sendTimeout="00:01:00" 
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
      <wsDualHttpBinding>
        <binding
          name="WSDualHttpBinding_ICacheSearch"
          closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00"
          receiveTimeout="00:01:00"
          sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          clientBaseAddress="http://localhost:5057/wsDualHttpBinding"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true"
          transactionFlow="false">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="CacheService.CachingService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:5055/CachingService/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="Search" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="CacheService.ICacheSearch" />
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="CacheService.ICacheService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:5055/CachingService/Search" binding="wsDualHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_ICacheSearch" contract="CacheService.ICacheSearch"
          name="WSDualHttpBinding_ICacheSearch" />
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:5055/CachingService" binding="wsHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ICacheService" contract="CacheService.ICacheService"
    name="WSHttpBinding_ICacheService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Finally, I created a simple Windows Forms app to test. It is declared as:

```
[CallbackBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
public partial class Form1 : Form, cacheService.ICacheSearchCallback
{
    InstanceContext context = null;
    cacheService.CacheServiceClient _service = null;
    cacheService.CacheSearchClient _proxy = null;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _syncContext = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current;
        _service = new cacheService.CacheServiceClient();
        this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

        context = new InstanceContext(this);
        _proxy = new cacheService.CacheSearchClient(context);

        RefreshList();
    }


    private void RefreshList()
    {
        _proxy.SearchCache("mySource");
    }


    public void OnCallback(object data)
    {
        this._data = data;
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this._data;
    }
```

The call to the service (_proxy.SearchCache("mySource")) successfully executes the method on the service and service calls _callback.OnCallback(outList). But the callback method implemented in my test app is never called and so the data are never conveyed to the test app.

Again, I have looked at every recent WCF article on SO and many other blogs and code sites. I feel like I need a another pair of eyes to point out the obvious so I can get back to work.

Many thanks,

Robert

Comment: Just to test. Can you run this code `Task.Run(()=>_proxy.SearchCache("mySource"));` in *RefreshList* ? I suspect your thread is blocked and can't process your callback.

Comment: I'm still using .NET 4, but System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _proxy.SearchCache("mySource")); runs without exception.

Comment: And? Is your callback method invoked now?

Comment: After adding an item to the cache, which calls the RefreshList() method, I get the following: There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:5055/CachingService/Search that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Comment: The inner exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:5055. Blocking?

Comment: I fixed the exception, but now getting "The message could not be transferred within the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. There was no space available in the reliable channel's transfer window. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout." which is new. Better than what have been seeing most of the day.